Existence of joint distribution
Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be real-valued random variables on a common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$. Does the joint distribution of $(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ exist? In other words, there there exist a probability space $(S,\mathcal G,Q)$ such that $$Q(A) = P\big(\{\omega\in\Omega : (X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)(\omega)\in A\}\big)$$ for all measurable $A$.
Since $X_i$ is measurable, the preimage $\{\omega\in\Omega : (X_1, X_2, ...., X_n)(\omega)\in A\}$ is measurable, too. Hence $Q$ is a well-defined real-valued function on $\mathcal G$. Moreover, $Q$ is a probability measure:

$Q(\emptyset) = 0$ as the preimage of the empty set is the empty set,
$Q(\mathbb R) = 1$ by definition of a probability measure,
$Q\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\right) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty Q(A_j)$ for any sequence of pairwise disjoint measurable sets $(A_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ as set union distributes over preimages

So I just showed that the joint distribution of a finite collection of real-valued random variables on a common probability space exists.
The reasoning can be adapted to any countable and even uncountable collections of random variables. Am I right assuming that for any collection of random variables (defined on the same probability space) the joint distribution exists?
I am asking this question because I frequently encounter the following requirement: "let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a sequence of real-valued random variables with existing joint distribution Q". Based on what I have shown, this assumption of an existing joint distribution is superfluous as it always exists.
Am I right or is there a mistake in proof/reasoning?

Your definition of joint distribution does not make sense. You have to consider Borel sets in $\mathbb R^{n}$ to define the joint distribution  of $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$.

isn't that implicit by the specifying real-valued random variables, i.e., $S = \mathbb R^n$, $\mathcal G$ = Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R^n$?

If $A$ is in $\mathbb R^{n}$ what is ${\omega\in\Omega : X_i(\omega)\in A}$?

This is indeed a problem... I re-define $Q$ to be $Q(A) = P({\omega\in\Omega : (X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)(\omega)\in A})$. Would this help? Eventually, I am just interested in an answer to the question: do I need to assume existence of the joint distribution or do I get it for free?

In general, Kolmogorov's theorem answers exactly your question in way more generality, see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem. For your special case, put $S = \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathcal{G}$ being Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Q$ be the law of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ considered as a $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued random variable, which is defined exactly as you write it, for Borel sets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. The work you should be doing is to check that this definition you wrote satisfy the properties of a probability measure, which should not be hard at all. In fact, with $S$ being any measurable space, the law of an $S$-valued random variable is defined.
